# Visual Studio Database Project: Deploy versus Publish

Tags: visual-studio, database-project

What is the difference between a Deploy and a Publish for a Visual Studio database project?  They both seem to accomplish pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use publish. Deploy does nothing when I invoke it from the build menu. If you right-click the project there is no deploy option and the build menu shows no deploy option with the project selected in solution explorer (VS2015).